# How to create a "Catalyst" to view data before x minutes from z timestamp and x minutes after z timestamp for every 'ABC' specific data

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssrs-2012

" I want a SSRS report that can identify all activations received within the last 5 minutes before the CNT signal was received from a store and signals that were received within 5 minutes after the CNT signal "

Need to know what is the best practice to achieve this goal - what to google to fix my query to make it easier to design in report builder

I have q query below but within SSRS I cant group it or expand it in a way useful for viewing
I have a proof of concept (image) but don't know how to approach the query to get to the result

a bit ambitious for a Jnr report writer!

[POC Catalyst Idea <<<<<-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li228.jpg)

```
DECLARE @Division varchar(2) = '*',
@SubDivision varchar(4) = '*',
@MainArea varchar(3) = '*',
@SubArea varchar(3) = '*',
@StartD datetime = '2022-03-29',
@StartTime Varchar(10) = '06:00:00',
@EndD datetime = '2022-03-29',
@EndTime Varchar(10) = '18:00:00',
@X int = 5,
@Catylist varchar(3) = 'CNT'

DECLARE @Arc varchar(100),
@Svr varchar(50),
@db varchar(50),
@Str varchar(max) = '',
@Qry varchar(max) = '',
@mon varchar(100) = '',
@StartDate varchar(20),
@EndDate varchar(20)

SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(11),@StartD,106) + ' ' + @StartTime
SET @EndDate = CONVERT(varchar(11),@EndD,106) + ' ' + @EndTime

SELECT @mon = IIF(UPPER(ServerName)=UPPER(@@ServerName),DatabaseName,'[' + ServerName + '].' + DatabaseName) + '.dbo.'
FROM maBranchModules WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Module = 'MONITOR'



CREATE TABLE #FirstBL
(CustId int, Signl varchar(10), StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime,Seq int,Catalyst char(1))

DECLARE Arc_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT SQLServer, SQLDatabase FROM RW_ArchiveDTL WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE StartDTTM >= DATEADD(month,-1,EOMONTH(@StartDate))
AND EndDTTM <= DATEADD(day,1,EOMONTH(@EndDate))
ORDER BY StartDTTM
OPEN Arc_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Arc_cursor INTO @Svr, @db

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF @Svr = @@ServerName
SET @Arc = @db + '.dbo.'
ELSE
SET @Arc = '[' + @Svr + '].' + @db + '.dbo.'

IF @Str = ''
SET @Str = 'INSERT INTO #FirstBL (CustId,Signl,StartTime,Seq)'
ELSE
SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'UNION ALL '

/*GET ALL CATYLIST SIGNALS IN DATE RANGE*/
SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'SELECT
a.CustId, a.FirstAlarm,a.SignalTime,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.CustId ORDER BY a.SignalTime) AS Seq
FROM ' + @Arc + 'ArchiveHistory AS a WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
' + @mon + 'Address AS b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.AddressId = b.AddressId
WHERE a.SignalTime >= ''' + CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,121) + '''
AND a.SignalTime < ''' + CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,121) + '''
AND a.FirstAlarm = ''' + @Catylist + '''
AND a.CustId > 0 '
IF @Division <> '*'
SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'AND b.Division = ''' + @Division + ''' '
IF @SubDivision <> '*'
SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'AND b.SubDivision = ''' + @SubDivision + ''' '
IF @MainArea <> '*'
SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'AND a.MainArea = ''' + @MainArea + ''' '
IF @SubArea <> '*'
SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'AND a.SubArea = ''' + @SubArea + ''' '

IF @Qry <> ''
SET @Qry = @Qry + char(13) + 'UNION ALL '

/*GET ALL SIGNALS FOR @X MINUTES BEFORE & AFTER CATYLIST SIGNAL RECEIVED*/
SET @Qry = @Qry + char(13) + 'SELECT DISTINCT
--a.CustId, b.StartTime, a.SignalTime, a.FirstAlarm, b.EndTime,
a.CustId, a.SignalTime, a.FirstAlarm, a.OBNumber,
c.CustCode, c.CustDesc, d.Division, d.SubDivision, d.MainArea, d.SubArea, c.SuspendMode
FROM ' + @Arc + 'ArchiveHistory AS a WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
#FirstBL AS b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.CustId = b.CustId INNER JOIN
' + @mon + 'Client AS c WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.CustId = c.CustId INNER JOIN
' + @mon + 'Address AS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.AddressId = d.AddressId
AND a.SignalTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute,-' + CONVERT(varchar,@X) + ',b.StartTime) AND b.EndTime '

FETCH NEXT FROM Arc_cursor INTO @Svr, @db
END
CLOSE Arc_cursor;
DEALLOCATE Arc_cursor;

SET @Str = @Str + char(13) + 'ORDER BY CustId, SignalTime'
EXEC(@Str)

/*CLEAN OUT ALL EXTRA CATYLIST SIGNALS THAT FALLS WITHIN @X OF "FIRST"*/
UPDATE #FirstBL SET EndTime = DATEADD(minute,@X,StartTime) WHERE Seq = 1

UPDATE a SET a.Catalyst = IIF(a.StartTime BETWEEN b.StartTime AND b.EndTime,'N','Y')
FROM #FirstBL AS a INNER JOIN
#FirstBL AS b ON a.CustId = b.CustId
WHERE b.Seq = 1
AND a.Seq > 1

DELETE FROM #FirstBL WHERE Catalyst = 'N'

DECLARE @N int
SET @N = 1

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #FirstBL WHERE EndTime IS NULL) > 0
begin
UPDATE #FirstBL SET EndTime = DATEADD(minute,@X,StartTime), Seq = @N + 1
WHERE Seq = (SELECT TOP 1 a.Seq FROM #FirstBL a WHERE #FirstBL.CustId = a.CustId AND Seq > @N ORDER BY a.Seq)

UPDATE a SET a.Catalyst = IIF(a.StartTime BETWEEN b.StartTime AND b.EndTime,'N','Y')
FROM #FirstBL AS a INNER JOIN
#FirstBL AS b ON a.CustId = b.CustId
WHERE b.Seq = @N
AND a.Seq > @N

DELETE FROM #FirstBL WHERE Catalyst = 'N'

Set @N = @N +1
end

/*ALL TOGETHER NOW*/
SET @Qry = @Qry + char(13) + 'ORDER BY CustId, SignalTime'
EXEC(@Qry)

/*GET RID OF THE #*/
DROP TABLE #FirstBL
```

Comment: why are you using `cursor` and `nolock` ? nolock is no magic speed button, and cursor is more like c# language thinking than sql. does it really have to be a big union all sql ? you should first solve this problem with one source, one db one server and without the dynamic sql, one simple sql with hard coded criterias in where clause so we can better see your grouping objectives. this kind of grouping can be solved by first extracting the significant points in time, then using subroutines and windowed functions

Comment: @jjdesign 
Thank you for the feedback
Cursor is used to get data from the archives as each month is written to there own database
nolock is a co. standard

I have taken you advice and tried to dumb it down for myself - trying to see if I can add multiple ROW_NUMBER to my query or to use a temp table
Been at it for a while with no luck - YET!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look behind and ahead 5 minutes, recommend just using APPLY. For example, here's how to find every match to a "CNT" event within 5 minutes

### Using APPLY to Find Events +/- 5 Minutes

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data 

CREATE TABLE #Data (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,SignalDateTime DATETIME2(0)
    ,FirstAlarm CHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO #Data VALUES 
 ('2022-03-29 10:06','LRQ')
,('2022-03-29 10:07','CNF')
,('2022-03-29 10:07','CNT')
,('2022-03-29 10:07','DNT')
,('2022-03-29 13:19','LRQ')
,('2022-03-29 13:20','CNF')
,('2022-03-29 13:20','CNT')
,('2022-03-29 13:20','DNT')
,('2022-03-29 13:24','LRQ')
,('2022-03-29 13:24','CNF')
,('2022-03-29 13:24','CNT')
,('2022-03-29 13:24','DNT')
,('2022-03-29 13:25','CNF')
,('2022-03-29 13:25','CNT')
,('2022-03-29 13:25','DNT')
,('2022-03-29 14:31','LRQ')
,('2022-03-29 14:31','CNF')
,('2022-03-29 14:31','CNT')
,('2022-03-29 14:31','DNT')

SELECT CNTGroupID = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.ID)
    ,*
FROM #Data AS A
CROSS APPLY (   
    SELECT *
    FROM #Data AS DTA
    WHERE DTA.FirstAlarm <> 'CNT'
    AND DTA.SignalDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(mi,-5,A.SignalDateTime) AND DATEADD(mi,5,A.SignalDateTime)
) AS B
WHERE A.FirstAlarm = 'CNT'
```

Comment: Thank you so much this does help me quite a bit. Learning new things every day. I really appreciate